# Associations with Mongoid

Tags: ruby, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations, mongoid

I have three simple models - `Car`, `Details` and `Details2`.
`Car` have lot of `Details` and `Details` have lot of `Details2`.

With MySQL and ActiveRecord I will set the associations like:

```
class Car
  has_many :details
end


class Detail
   belongs_to :car
end
```

In the view, where I have a list of Car, I have:

```
<% @cars.each do |car| -%>
  <%=car.details.count%> #uninitialized constant Details
<% end %>
```

**EDIT2:**
This is what I have in **cars** table:

```
db.cars.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4efe69716f85ce447a000054"), "name" : "bmw", "descr" : "asasgasga as gas gas ", "updated_at" : "Sat Dec 31 2011 02:46:25 GMT+0100 (CET)", "created_at" : "Sat Dec 31 2011 02:46:25 GMT+0100 (CET)" }
```

and **details**:

```
db.details.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f01106d6f85ce6b850000b8"), "car_id" : ObjectId("4efe69716f85ce447a000054"), "name" : "20120102030325", "descr" : "dsg", "updated_at" : "Mon Jan 02 2012 03:03:25 GMT+0100 (CET)", "created_at" : "Mon Jan 02 2012 03:03:25 GMT+0100 (CET)" }
```

And in **CarsController** I have in this action only:

```
def index
  @cars = Car.all
end
```

that's all what I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse what you know from ActiveRecord. `has_many` and `belongs_to` [work just fine](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/1-n.html) in Mongoid.

But you can take advantage of document databases (which MongoDB is) and use some embedding. For `embedded_in` to work correctly you have to have `embeds_one` or `embeds_many` on the other end. See http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-1.html

```
  class Person
    include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_one :name
  end

  class Name
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :vorname, type: String
    field :nachname, type: String
    embedded_in :person
  end
```

Comment: yes, I am sorry, my fault. I need some sleep already. But now when I try `car.details.count`, so I will get `uninitialized constant Details`

Comment: Post more code! :-) Definitions look ok, but do you do with them?

Comment: I updated again the original post - what I updated, those are the only operations, what I do, I do nothing else

Comment: Is your code exactly like this, with cars, details and such? Or probably your classes have other names that pluralizer might have problems with?

Comment: yes, exactly. But now - I tried to change in `Car` class `has_many :details` to `has_many :dateil` and in the `view` `car.details.count` to `car.detail.count` and it works... I absolutely don't understand it...

Comment: Yeah, maybe word inflector has some problem with this word. For an experiment, try renaming `details` to `posts`. This name is known to work, it's from official doc! :-)